# How to get file size in bytes from shell script?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am trying to create a script to write an XML file for Apple's ITMSP Transporter files for uploading metadata to the App Store. Requirements for screenshots are filename, MD5 checksum and filesize in bytes.

MD5 checksum is easy and be can be retrieved with `md5 -q image.png`

I am however having a hard time trying to get the byte size of the image file. If I use `du -k image.png` command, it returns the size rounded up in kilo bytes. So for example if the actual size is 5722 bytes, `du` will return 8 (as in 8K or 8192 bytes) which is not correct. And the default for `du` is in 512 byte chunks but still rounds the value up (so it will return 16 instead of 8).

I am running Lion OSX 10.7.4.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

One easy approach is:

```
stat -f%z image.png
```

`stat` normally spits out a bunch of data, but the `%z` format just selects the size in bytes.

Comment: Awesome! I have not used that command before. +1 for speedy response of 2 minutes after I posted it!

Comment: stat: invalid option -- '%' :(

Comment: What if I want it in, say, megabytes ?

Comment: `stat -f \"%z bytes\"`  should work for you saravanabawa

Comment: @ArthurCorenzan `stat -f \"%z megabytes\"`

Comment: @pixel67 Er, no... that'll just display the size in bytes with the word "megabytes" after it

Comment: You can also use `wc -c image.png` It would output the number of bytes in the input file, right?

Comment: @user3019105 Not a good idea. Depending on your locale settings, `wc` may try to count UTF-8 characters, rather than bytes, which won't work properly on binary data.

Comment: That was what I wanted to hear, thank you for the elucidation! I will keep that in mind! So definitely `stat -f%z image.png`!

Answer (score 13):

On OSX do `stat -f "%z bytes"`.

Comment: On my machine (macOS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)) that doesn't work. However, this does: stat -c %s FILE